# Algebraically characterizing morphisms of commutative rings that are a homeomorphism on the prime spectra

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let us say that a morphism $\varphi\colon A\to B$ of rings (commutative, with unit) is a **homeomorphism on the (prime) spectra** iff the corresponding map $\operatorname{Spec}B\to\operatorname{Spec}A$ (which takes a prime ideal of $B$ to its inverse image in $A$) is a homeomorphism for the Zariski topology.

**Main question:** can we characterize such $\varphi$ in a purely ring-theoretic way?

(To be very precise, ideally¹ I'd like a characterization that only involves the ring elements, not ideals: that is, a single statement in the first-order two-sorted language of two rings, one sort for elements of $A$ and one for elements of $B$, whose operations are the ring operations on $A$ and $B$ and the ring morphism from one sort to the other, with quantifiers allowed over elements of $A$ or of $B$.  But I'd be happy with a little less than that, e.g., a statement that also involves quantifiers over the natural numbers like “any power of $a$”, or one over polynomials with coefficients in $A$ or $B$ is also fine.  What I *don't* want are quantifiers over ideals or other kinds of subsets of $A$ or $B$.)

1. Pun unintended.

**Alternative questions:** purely ring-theoretic characterizations of any of the following properties of $\varphi$ are also of interest to me:

- $\varphi$ is bijective on the spectra (this is indeed weaker than being a homeomorphism, as the example of $k[t] \to k[t,t^{-1}]\times k$ given by $f \mapsto (f,f(0))$ shows),
- $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism to its image on the spectra,
- $\varphi$ is a universal homeomorphism on the spectra (i.e., a homeomorphism on the spectra which remains such after tensoring by any $A\to A'$),
- $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism on the *maximal* spectra (i.e., gives rise to a map $\operatorname{Specmax}B\to\operatorname{Specmax}A$ which is a homeomorphism, where $\operatorname{Specmax}$ is the subset of $\operatorname{Spec}$ consisting of maximal ideals — including the statement that $\varphi^{-1}(\mathfrak{m})$ is maximal in $A$ for any maximal $\mathfrak{m}$ in $B$),

— or other such variations (e.g., $\varphi$ is bijective on the maximal spectra).  I don't know a purely ring-theoretic characterization of *any* of these.

The closest I know is EGA IV.2.4.5, which states that an integral surjective radiciel morphism of schemes is a universal homeomorphism and that the converse holds if the target is locally noetherian.

Comment: There are some results in this direction for *universal* homeomorphisms (i.e. radicial maps that are bijective on spectra); see Tag [0CN6](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0CN6). In particular, have a look at Tag [0CNE](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0CNE).

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**  Sorry, what I originally wrote was the opposite of what I should have said, thanks to Will and Remy.  The criteria I wrote was that the ring has *no* subintegral/weakly subintegral extension (in the relevant overring).

A (finite/integral) extension of rings $R \subseteq S$ is called *subintegral* in the commutative algebra literature if it is a bijection on prime spectra and the extensions of residue fields are all isomorphisms.

My recollection is $R \subseteq S$ is subintegral if and only if for each $x \in S$ there is a sequence of extensions $$R \subseteq R[x_1] \subseteq R[x_1, x_2] \subseteq \dots \subseteq R[x_1, \dots, x_n]$$ such that $x \in R[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ and such that $x_{i+1}^2, x_{i+1}^3 \in R[x_i]$ for all $i$.

See the papers of Greco-Traverso, Haimann, Leahy-Vitulli, Swan, Vitulli, etc.

Being a universal homeomorphism is also called *weakly subintegral* in some of the commutative algebra literature.  Ie, a (integral/finite) inclusion $R \subseteq S$ is called *weakly subintegral* if it induces a bijection on prime spectra and the induces maps on residue fields are isomorphisms.  If $R$ is local and the residual characteristic is $p$, then I believe $S$ being weakly subintegral over $R$ is characterized by the property that for each $x \in S$, there is a sequence of extensions:
$$R \subseteq R[x_1] \subseteq R[x_1, x_2] \subseteq \dots \subseteq R[x_1, \dots, x_n]$$ such that $x \in R[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ and such that, for every $i$, either $x_{i+1}^2, x_{i+1}^3 \in R[x_i]$ or that $px_{i+1}, x_{i+1}^p \in R[x_i]$.

I believe a paper of Leahy-Vitulli (I think?), and an erratum, also explores the maximal spectrum question for varieties.

Comment: The characterization of subintegral sounds wrong to me. If we take $R = k[x^2, x^3]$ and $S= k[x]$ then the condition in terms of elements is not satisfied but the map is a bijection on prime spectra with the extensions of residue fields all isomorphisms. On the other hand if $R$ and $S$ are fields then the condition in terms of elements is always satisfied but the extension of residue fields is usually not an isomorphism.

Comment: If you ask that $\operatorname{Spec} S \to \operatorname{Spec} R$ induces isomorphisms on residue fields and is *universally* a homeomorphism, then the criterion is somehow the opposite of what you wrote: $S$ is iteratively generated by adjoining elements $x_i$ such that $x_i^2,x_i^3 \in R[x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1}]$. See Tag [0CND](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0CND).

Comment: You are right, I screwed that up.  Sorry.  I will fix that.